# How to scale CAShapeLayer to different UIImageView

Tags: swift3, uibezierpath, cashapelayer

I have a UIImageView that you can tap on and it draws a circle.  I store the location of the circles in an Array of Dictionaries.  This allows me to "replay" the drawing of the circles.  However, when the UIImageView is a different size from the original, the circles don't scale to the new UIImageView.

How can I get the circles to scale?  For demonstration purposes, the top picture is the size of the UIImageView used for input and the second one is the size for replay.

Inputing the circles:

[image]

Replay the circles (the circles should be in the blue UIImageView

[image]

```
import Foundation
import UIKit

class DrawPuck {

    func drawPuck(circle: CGPoint, circleColour: CGColor, circleSize: CGFloat, imageView: UIImageView) {

        let circleBezierPath = UIBezierPath(arcCenter: CGPoint(x: circle.x,y: circle.y), radius: CGFloat(circleSize), startAngle: CGFloat(0), endAngle:CGFloat(M_PI * 2), clockwise: true)

        let shapeLayer = CAShapeLayer()

        shapeLayer.path = circleBezierPath.cgPath

        //change the fill color
        shapeLayer.fillColor = circleColour

        //you can change the stroke color
        shapeLayer.strokeColor = UIColor.white.cgColor

        //you can change the line width
        shapeLayer.lineWidth = 0.5

        imageView.layer.addSublayer(shapeLayer)

    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

I was able to resolve this with `CATransform3DMakeScale`  As long as I keep the original aspect ratio of the original image it works great.

```
    let width = yellowImageView.frame.width / blueImageView.frame.width
    let height = yellowImageView.frame.height / blueImageView.frame.height

    shapeLayer.transform = CATransform3DMakeScale(height, width, 1.0)

    view.layer.addSublayer(shapeLayer)
```